# FATAL EXCEPTION: main android in google play services

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I try to get current location and user activity, following the guide from 
http://j.mp/io13-location the "checkpoint_final"

but i got those error when i run the program.

my logCat:

```
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798): Process:   com.android.google.codelab.location, PID: 3798
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.google.codelab.location/com.android.google.codelab.location.LocationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.dk.bB(Unknown Source)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.fm.a(Unknown Source)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.fm$c.bB(Unknown Source)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.fl.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.fm.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.fm.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.android.google.codelab.location.LocationActivity.restartLocationClient(LocationActivity.java:248)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at com.android.google.codelab.location.LocationActivity.onResume(LocationActivity.java:197)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
02-21 18:12:38.439: E/AndroidRuntime(3798):     ... 12 more
```

my Code

```
public class LocationActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public static String TAG = "LocationActivity";
public static boolean isAppForeground = false;
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_ON_CREATE_REQUEST_CODE = 4055;
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_ON_RESUME_REQUEST_CODE = 4056;

// Shared variables
private GoogleMap mMap;
private Dialog errorDialog;

// Location Request variables
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private TextView mLocationStatus;
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback();
private Location mLastLocation;
private static final int LOCATION_UPDATES_INTERVAL = 10000; // Setting 10 sec interval for location updates

// Activity Recognition variables
private ActivityRecognitionClient mActivityRecognitionClient;
private ActivityRecognitionCallback mActivityRecognitionCallback = new ActivityRecognitionCallback();
public static final String ACTION_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION = 
        "com.android.google.codelab.location.LocationActivity.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION";
private static final int ACTIVITY_UPDATES_INTERVAL = 4000;
private PendingIntent mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent;
private Switch mSwitch;
private ActivityRecognitionIntentReceiver mActivityRecognitionIntentReceiver;

// Geo Fencing variables
private GeoFenceCallback mGeoFenceCallback = new GeoFenceCallback();
private int id = 0;
private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 100;
private HashMap<String, Circle> mGeoFences;
private HashMap<String, Circle> mTriggeringFences;
public static final String ACTION_GEOFENCE =
        "com.android.google.codelab.location.LocationActivity.GEOFENCE";
private TextView mGeoFenceStatus;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    checkGooglePlayServiceAvailability(ERROR_DIALOG_ON_CREATE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private void init() {
    // Initialize map
    if (mMap == null) {
        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment myMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
    }

    // Initialize Location Client
    mLocationStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location_status);

    if (mLocationClient == null) {
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, mLocationCallback, mLocationCallback);
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Location Client connect");
        if (!(mLocationClient.isConnected() || mLocationClient.isConnecting())) {
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }
    }

    // Initialize Action Recognition
    if (mActivityRecognitionClient == null) {
        mActivityRecognitionClient =
                new ActivityRecognitionClient(this, 
                        mActivityRecognitionCallback, mActivityRecognitionCallback);
    }

    mSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.swtich);
    mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                startActivityDetection(buttonView);
            } else {
                stopActivityDetection(buttonView);
            }
        }
    });

    if (mActivityRecognitionIntentReceiver == null) {
        mActivityRecognitionIntentReceiver = new ActivityRecognitionIntentReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mActivityRecognitionIntentReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(LocationActivity.ACTION_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION));
    }

    // Initialize Geo Fencing
    mGeoFenceStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.geo_fence_status);

    if (mGeoFences == null) {
        mGeoFences = new HashMap<String, Circle>();
    }

    if (mTriggeringFences == null) {
        mTriggeringFences = new  HashMap<String, Circle>();
    }

    // Setup map to allow adding Geo Fences
    mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(mGeoFenceCallback);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Indicate the application is in background
    isAppForeground = false;

    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Indicate the application is in foreground
    isAppForeground = true;

    checkGooglePlayServiceAvailability(ERROR_DIALOG_ON_RESUME_REQUEST_CODE);

    restartLocationClient();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mActivityRecognitionIntentReceiver);
    mActivityRecognitionIntentReceiver = null;
}

private void checkGooglePlayServiceAvailability(int requestCode) {
    // Query for the status of Google Play services on the device
    int statusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if (statusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        init();
    } else {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(statusCode)) {
            errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(statusCode,
                    this, requestCode);
            errorDialog.show();
        } else {
            // Handle unrecoverable error
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case ERROR_DIALOG_ON_CREATE_REQUEST_CODE:
            init();
            break;
        case ERROR_DIALOG_ON_RESUME_REQUEST_CODE:
            restartLocationClient();
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void restartLocationClient() {
    if (!(mLocationClient.isConnected() || mLocationClient.isConnecting())) {
        mLocationClient.connect(); // Somehow it becomes connected here
        return;
    }
    LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
    request.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATES_INTERVAL);
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, mLocationCallback);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(R.string.clear_map);
    menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            clearMap();
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

public void clearMap() {
    mMap.clear();
    mLastLocation = null;
    mGeoFenceCallback.removeGeoFences();
}

private class LocationCallback implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Location Client connected");

        // Display last location
        Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        if (location != null) {
            handleLocation(location);
        }

        // Request for location updates
        LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
        request.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATES_INTERVAL);
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, mLocationCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Location Client disconnected by the system");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Location Client connection failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "onLocationChanged: location == null");
            return;
        }
        // Add a marker iff location has changed.
        if (mLastLocation != null &&
            mLastLocation.getLatitude() == location.getLatitude() &&
            mLastLocation.getLongitude() == location.getLongitude()) {
            return;
        }

        handleLocation(location);
    }

    private void handleLocation(Location location) {
        // Update the mLocationStatus with the lat/lng of the location
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "LocationChanged == @" +
                location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
        mLocationStatus.setText("Location changed @" + location.getLatitude() + "," +
                location.getLongitude());

        // Add a marker of that location to the map
        LatLng latlongzoom = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());
        String snippet = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions().position(latlongzoom));
        marker.setSnippet(snippet);
        marker.setTitle(snippet);

        // Center the map to the first marker 
        if (mLastLocation == null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.
                    newCameraPosition(CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),
                    (float) 16.0)));
        }
        mLastLocation = location;
    }
};

public void startActivityDetection(View v) {
    if (!mActivityRecognitionClient.isConnected()) {
        mActivityRecognitionClient.connect();
    }
}

public void stopActivityDetection(View v) {
    if (mActivityRecognitionClient.isConnected()) {
        mActivityRecognitionClient.removeActivityUpdates(mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent);
        mActivityRecognitionClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private class ActivityRecognitionCallback implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Activity Recognition Client connected");

        // Request activity updates
        Intent intent = new Intent(LocationActivity.this,
                ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(LocationActivity.ACTION_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION);
        mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(LocationActivity.this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mActivityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(ACTIVITY_UPDATES_INTERVAL,
                mActivityRecognitionPendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Activity Recognition Client disconnected by the system");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG,
                "Activity Recognition Client connection failed " + result.getErrorCode());
    }
};

private class GeoFenceCallback implements OnMapLongClickListener,
    OnAddGeofencesResultListener, OnRemoveGeofencesResultListener {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG,
                "onMapLongClick == " + point.latitude + "," + point.longitude);
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
        circleOptions.center(point).radius(GEOFENCE_RADIUS).strokeColor(
                android.graphics.Color.BLUE).strokeWidth(2);
        Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
        String key = Integer.toString(id);
        id++;
        mGeoFences.put(key, circle);
        addGeoFences();
    }

    // Creates Geofence objects from all circles on the map and calls addGeofences API.
    private void addGeoFences() {
        List<Geofence> list = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Circle> entry : mGeoFences.entrySet()) {
            Circle circle = entry.getValue();
            Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "points == " +
                    circle.getCenter().latitude + "," +
                    circle.getCenter().longitude);
            Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                   .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                   .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                                       Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                   .setCircularRegion(circle.getCenter().latitude,
                                      circle.getCenter().longitude,
                                      (float) circle.getRadius())
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE).build();
            list.add(geofence);
        }
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        // Clear off all the currently triggering geo_fences before new fences
        // are added.
        for (Circle triggeringGeoFence : mTriggeringFences.values()) {
            triggeringGeoFence.remove();
        }
        mTriggeringFences.clear();
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "addingGeoFences size = " + list.size());
        mLocationClient.addGeofences(list, getPendingIntent(), this);
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_GEOFENCE);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(LocationActivity.this,
                GeoFenceIntentReceiver.class));
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LocationActivity.this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    private void removeGeoFences() {
        List<String> requestIdsForRemoval = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (mGeoFences.isEmpty()) return;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Circle> entry : mGeoFences.entrySet()) {
            String requestId = entry.getKey();
            Circle circle = entry.getValue();
            if (circle != null) {
                circle.remove();
                id --;
                Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "RemoveGeoFence requestId == " + requestId);
                Circle triggeringCircle = mTriggeringFences.get(requestId);
                if (triggeringCircle != null) {
                    triggeringCircle.remove();
                }
                requestIdsForRemoval.add(requestId);
            }
        }
        mGeoFences.clear();
        mTriggeringFences.clear();
        mLocationClient.removeGeofences(requestIdsForRemoval, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddGeofencesResult(int statusCode,
            String[] geofenceRequestIds) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < geofenceRequestIds.length - 1; ++i) {
            builder.append(geofenceRequestIds[i]);
            builder.append(",");
        }
        builder.append(geofenceRequestIds[geofenceRequestIds.length - 1]);
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Added Geofences == " 
                + statusCodeToString(statusCode) + " " + builder.toString());
        mGeoFenceStatus.setText("Added Geofences "
                + statusCodeToString(statusCode) + " " + builder.toString());
    }

    private String statusCodeToString(int statusCode) {
        switch(statusCode) {
            case LocationStatusCodes.SUCCESS :
                return "SUCCESS";
            case LocationStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE :
                return "GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE";
            case LocationStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES :
                return "GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES";
            case LocationStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS :
                return "GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS";
            case LocationStatusCodes.ERROR :
                return "ERROR";
        }
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveGeofencesByPendingIntentResult(int statusCode, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveGeofencesByRequestIdsResult(int statusCode,
            String[] geofenceRequestIds) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < geofenceRequestIds.length - 1; ++i) {
            builder.append(geofenceRequestIds[i]);
            builder.append(",");
        }
        builder.append(geofenceRequestIds[geofenceRequestIds.length - 1]);
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Removed Geofence " +
                statusCodeToString(statusCode) + " " + builder.toString());
        mGeoFenceStatus.setText("Removed Geofences request_ids = " +
                builder.toString() + " " + statusCodeToString(statusCode));
    }

};

// Triggered when startAcitivity method is called in GeoFenceIntentReceiver.
// Updates UI as geofences are entered/exited.
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    setIntent(intent);
    boolean receiverStarted =
            intent.getBooleanExtra("RECEIVER_STARTED", false);
    if (!receiverStarted) {
        return;
    }
    Bundle bundle = intent.getParcelableExtra("geo_fences");
    ArrayList<String> requestIds =
            bundle.getStringArrayList("request_ids");
    if (requestIds == null) {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "request_ids == null");
        return;
    }
    int transition = intent.getIntExtra("transition", -2);

    for (String requestId : requestIds) {
        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Triggering Geo Fence requestId "
                + requestId);
        if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
            Circle circle = mGeoFences.get(requestId);
            if (circle == null) {
                continue;
            }
            Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "triggering_geo_fences enter == "
                    + requestId);

            // Add a superimposed red circle when a geofence is entered and
            // put the corresponding object in triggering_fences.
            CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
            circleOptions.center(circle.getCenter())
                    .radius(circle.getRadius())
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(100,100, 0, 0));
            Circle newCircle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
            mTriggeringFences.put(requestId, newCircle);
        } else if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
            Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG,  "triggering_geo_fences exit == "
                    + requestId);
            Circle circle = mTriggeringFences.get(requestId);
            if (circle == null) {
                continue;
            }
            // Remove the superimposed red circle from the map and the
            // corresponding Circle object from triggering_fences hash_map.
            circle.remove();
            mTriggeringFences.remove(requestId);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

}

2nd class

```
public class ActivityRecognitionIntentService extends IntentService {
public ActivityRecognitionIntentService() {
    super("ActivityRecognitionIntentService");
}

public ActivityRecognitionIntentService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() != LocationActivity.ACTION_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) {
        return;
    }
    if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult
                .extractResult(intent);
        DetectedActivity detectedActivity = result
                .getMostProbableActivity();
        int activityType = detectedActivity.getType();

        Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "activity_type == " + activityType);

        // Put the activity_type as an intent extra and send a broadcast.
        Intent send_intent = new Intent(
                LocationActivity.ACTION_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION);
        send_intent.putExtra("activity_type", activityType);
        sendBroadcast(send_intent);
    }
}
}
```

edited add the main part of the code

Comment: Hard to say if you are doing things correctly without seeing your code, but the log says *Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.*. Are you doing that ?

Comment: sorry, just added the code

Comment: What exactly is line # 248 in your LocationActivity code ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Modify your `restartLocationClient()` Method like this:

```
private void restartLocationClient() {

if (mLocationClient == null) {
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, mLocationCallback, mLocationCallback);
    Log.v(LocationActivity.TAG, "Location Client connect");
    if (!(mLocationClient.isConnected() || mLocationClient.isConnecting())) 
    {
     mLocationClient.connect(); // Somehow it becomes connected here
     return;
    }
}

 LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
 request.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATES_INTERVAL);
 request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
 mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, mLocationCallback);

}
```

It seems that your `mLocationClient` is null in this Method. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late for this answer.

But for future reference, I'll post it anyways.

Basically, we have to understand the `onConnect()` method better. I find the explanation in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107237/not-connected-call-connect-or-wait-for-onconnected-to-be-called) to be useful.

From there the workaround for this issue is pretty much straightforward.

Solution: `restartLocationClient()` is only called when `mLocationClient.isConnected()` returns true.

So, in your `onResume` method should look like the following:

```
if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
    restartLocationClient();
}
```

Now it will work.