# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() - YouTube API

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

I am trying to get the ThumbnailView working on my ArrayAdapter but I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.i(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.k(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.p.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView$a.a(Unknown Source)
```

My ArrayAdapter looks like this:

[Code for ArrayAdapter](http://pastebin.com/C4wtBAGy)

My xml video_items.xml Looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listviewbox"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Video Thumbnail -->
    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/panelcolor"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <!-- Video Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_thumbnail"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/videotext"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: do you get the solution? I having same error

Answer (score 6):

The same happened to me when showing `YoutubeThumbnailView`s inside a long ListView. I found the solution mentioned f.e. here:
https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/2#issuecomment-58913900
or here: 
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7533#c6

The solution is wrapping the `YoutubeThumbnailView` inside a `ViewHolder` object, keeping track of its initialization state. The `initialize(..)` method may not be called multiple times.

Unfortunately the exception doesn't lead there quickly.

Answer (score 0):

refers to: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289106/java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-connected-call-connect-and-wait-for-onco/47693216#47693216)

I have the same problem
"`YouTubeThumbnailView Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called`"
in RecyclerView.Adapter by scrolling quickly and there are 3 youtube thumbnails in the recylerView.

In the adapter I put like this:
a field: `private boolean readyForLoadingYoutubeThumbnail = true;`
and at onBindViewHolder

```
/**
 * https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35176819#c6
 * https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/2#issuecomment-58913900
 * YouTubeThumbnailView Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called
 */
Log.d(TAG, "readyForLoadingYoutubeThumbnail" + readyForLoadingYoutubeThumbnail);
final YouTubeInitializationResult result = YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(activity);
if (readyForLoadingYoutubeThumbnail) {
    Log.d(TAG, "initializing for youtube thumbnail view...");
    readyForLoadingYoutubeThumbnail = false;
    holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize("aaaaaaaaaaaaa", new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(final YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videoId);
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView childYouTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                    childYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.release(); // spy ga memory lick
                }

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.release(); // spy ga memory lick
                }
            });
            youTubeThumbnailView.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123, 123, 123), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

            readyForLoadingYoutubeThumbnail = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            //do nohing.. ada error, tambahin method ini jalan, error-nya lupa...
            readyForLoadingYoutubeThumbnail = true;
        }
    });
}
```

It is works for me...